# Cloned elements values not returned on Submit of form in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form in which the fields are cloned to add the fields to the form dynamically. I'm also removing some of the fields from form.

All addition and removal of elements are done using javascript and jquery using clone(), append() and remove() methods.

But on submit of form the values of the fields added dynamically are not returned in parameter list on submit of form. The values of fields removed still appear in parameters list.

What I observe is the dynamically added or removed elements are not recognized by rails and considering only the elements present in form initially when page was loaded.

Can any one suggest why is this behavior seen.

Comment: This issue got solved. The problem was that after I clone I changed the IDs of the cloned elements. But the values returned depends on the   name attribute of the element on submit. Changing the names of cloned elements fixed the problem. Hope this helps others facing similar issue.